# how replace all spaces in a text file with one character?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, replace

i have a text file like below :

```
string string
string                 string
string   string
string          string
```

i want to replace all these spaces with pipe (|) character.
is there any method in c# for doing that?

i am using the below codes for read and write on file :
[How do I read and edit a .txt file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368539/how-do-i-read-and-edit-a-txt-file-in-c)

**EDIT:**
after using the codes in the accepted answer i got the  below error in line of
**System.IO.File.WriteAllLines( ...**:

> Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\DevServer\10.0\infilename.txt'.

[Solves by absolute path]

**thanks for comments and answers :**
not each space with one pipe -> all spaces in each line with one pipe...

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @MoonLight - If you don't supply an absolute path (e.g. C:\infilename.txt) then it will attempt to resolve the filename relative to the directory that contains the executing assembly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the aanund's answer in:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(
    "outfilename.txt",
    System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("infilename.txt").Select(line =>
        string.Join("|",
            line.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        )
    ).ToArray()
);
```

Comment: Of course you have to turn infilename.txt into your file name! And outfilename.txt into your output file name

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(
    "outfilename.txt",
    System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("infilename.txt").Select(line =>
        System.Text.RegularExpression.Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", "|")
        )
    ).ToArray()
);
```

Note I just copied from the link and changed it to search for whitespace and replace that with a pipe.

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you are looking for

```
var regex = new Regex("[ ]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
regex.Replace(inputString, replaceCharacter);
```

after you read the whole file, use this regex and write it back into your file.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using regex:

```
string text = "test    test   test         test";
string cleanText = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, @"\s+", "|");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Just Replace:

```
      string original  = "test   test  test test";
      string formatted = original.Replace("  ", " ").Replace(" ", "|");
```

replace all occurrences of 2 adjacent spaces with just 1 space, then replace the final space with the pipe.