# using .replace to replace a word in text document (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, replace

currently have the following code:

```
    string[] fileLineString = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/Users.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < fileLineString.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] userPasswordPair = fileLineString[i].Split(' ');

        if (Session["user"].ToString() == userPasswordPair[0])
        {
            userPasswordPair[i].Replace(userPasswordPair[1], newPasswordTextBox.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

the text file is set out as: 'username' 'password

what i'm trying to do is be able to edit the password and replace it with a new one using my code, but my code seems to do nothing and the text file just stays the same.

Comment: use `Equals` for string compare over `==`

Comment: were do you save the new lines to file ?

Comment: @WhileTrueSleep String overload `==` operator to compare contents of a string

Comment: if (Session["user"].ToString().Equals.userPasswordPair[0])

doesn't work

Comment: Also you're reading the lines, but I don't see where you're "writing" the lines

Comment: The main point, is that `Replace` method returns a new string, it doesn't change the string you are replacing. You probably need `userPasswordPair[i] = userPasswordPair[i].Replace(...`, if other logic is correct

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368539/how-do-i-read-and-edit-a-txt-file-in-c

Comment: hmm, i thought replace would do the writing bit for me? e.g replace the old password with new password? But you're probably right since this code doesn't work. Thanks for link will give a read.

Comment: Yes, but you need to write the data back to the file.

Comment: @AnthonyJohnson `if(Session["user"].ToString().Equals(userPasswordPair[0]))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string[] fileLineString = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/Users.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < fileLineString.Length; i++)
{
    string[] userPasswordPair = fileLineString[i].Split(' ');

    if (Session["user"].ToString() == userPasswordPair[0])
    {
        // set the new password in the same list and save the file
        fileLineString[i] = Session["user"].ToString() + " " + newPasswordTextBox.Text;
        File.WriteAllLines((Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/Users.txt"), fileLineString);
        break; // exit from the for loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. At the moment, you're not storing the file.
2. Your replace is not assigned to a variable (Replace does not edit or write anything, it just returns the new string object).

**Corrected code:**

```
string[] fileLineString = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/Users.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < fileLineString.Length; i++)
{
    string[] userPasswordPair = fileLineString[i].Split(' ');

    if (Session["user"].ToString() == userPasswordPair[0])
    {
        fileLineString[i] = fileLineString[i].Replace(userPasswordPair[1], newPasswordTextBox.Text);
        break;
    }
}

File.WriteAllLines((Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/Users.txt", fileLineString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        String _userName = "User";
        String _newPassword = "Password";
        // Reading All line from file
        String _fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("filePath").ToString();
        // Pattern which user password like to changed            
        string _regPettern = String.Format(@"{0} ?(?<pwd>\w+)[\s\S]*?", _userName);
        Regex _regex2 = new Regex(_regPettern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        String _outPut = Regex.Replace(_fileContent, _regPettern, m => m.Groups[1] + " " + _newPassword);
        // Writing to file file
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("filePath", _outPut);
```