# Simultaneous Reading and Writing of a file in C#

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to read and write a file simultaneously in C#. I have read many threads here and in MSDNA but none seem to work with my needs. 
My file has a series of numbers separated with a comma. A huge amount of numbers to be exact. A sample line from my data is this

```
-0.1171695,0.03270377,2.420116,-0.02128719,0.9612453,0.2460478,-0.1225349,-0.110185,0.07739609,2.500247,-0.2783474,-0.06909045,-0.01818598,0.9578197,-0.1089995,0.456151,2.639686,0.3486561,-0.0008622027,-0.002657401,0.9372466,-0.1170361,0.6441286,2.674476,0.08662115,0.001171953,-0.01347759,0.9961495,-0.2623751,0.3104511,2.600713,-0.002028131,0.004831213,0.9220369,-0.3870664,-0.3145202,0.123338,2.49155,0.217727,0.4528476,-0.2009471,0.8409188,-0.2771441,-0.07509593,2.299996,0.2185546,3.817581E-09,7.635163E-09,0.9758247,-0.2690773,-0.1254997,2.259336,-0.02814693,0.0009682054,-0.03436448,0.9990125,0.01672855,0.3196935,2.572941,0.001961287,0.005368799,0.9392719,0.3431264,0.08505877,0.1033191,2.450031,0.1364797,-0.3903133,0.161962,0.8959894,0.03953359,-0.08940583,2.255897,0.2523192,7.699712E-09,0,0.967644,0.01856858,-0.1507191,2.211281,0.004362902,0.0004109977,0.09378911,0.9955825,-0.1821601,-0.03123568,2.403718,4.035548E-09,-3.067017E-07,0.9231187,-0.384515,-0.2238743,-0.4083549,2.266029,-0.05534944,0.02699615,-0.3286877,0.9424288,-0.2095885,-0.7422835,2.178757,-0.06393463,-0.003723484,-0.0580211,0.9962591,-0.2166772,-0.7653325,2.087598,0.5079094,0.03407073,-0.05760901,0.8588064,-0.05478298,-0.01793054,2.37413,8.070093E-09,-3.066635E-07,0.9232336,0.3842392,0.004473582,-0.3737353,2.252681,-0.09306445,-0.04594634,0.3224528,0.9408783,0.004849254,-0.7096405,2.178587,-0.03546751,0.003154774,0.08854229,0.9954358,-0.005173458,-0.7367281,2.088935,0.5053017,0.02486493,-0.04239483,0.861542,63507242650167
```

it actually takes up 24 lines in wordpad. each single line. What I want to do is go to the last number of each line, alter it, and save it back in the file. All the simultaneous writer reader source codes I found are working with append. I do not wish to append at the end of the file. I wish to get the last number from each line, and put the modified back in. I want the rest of the data to remain intact. How may I do that?

Comment: I don't see why this requires simultaneous reading & writing.

Comment: You can't read and write simultaneously. You'll have to read the file into a string or object, make the edit, then overwrite the file.

Comment: Similar question and some code that can get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368539/how-do-i-read-and-edit-a-txt-file-in-c

Comment: @tmoore82 Would a string be sufficient in order to read hundreds of lines of data like the line above? What type of object should I use?

Comment: You cannot "insert" bytes into a file, you can only overrite them, so this is only an option if the number you are overwriting consumes the *exact* same number of bytes in the file as the original.

Comment: @JohnDemetriou A collection (probably `List`) of strings  where each string is a line probably makes more sense here.  If you don't have enough memory to store the entire file then you'd need to write the data to a new file as you go along, then delete the old one and rename the new one after you finished your processing.

Comment: @Servy's idea of using a 'List' is a good one. If you know you're going to edit each line, that makes it easier. But my understanding is that a single string could be up to 2 gigs, so in terms of your standard text file, it'd have to be pretty ginormous to approach that limit.

Comment: @tmoore82 The problem there is that you're then modifying that string repeatedly, and the operations on it are going to be both harder to implement and less efficient in both memory and time, than if you break it up into lines.  It may well be *possible* though, yes.

Comment: @sServy: Great point. I totally agree. `List` makes much more sense for this task.

Comment: "A huge amount of numbers to be exact." really?

Comment: @Greg well "the huge amount of numbers" was put in my question to make people think about the fact if it could be contained inside a String. Each line consists up to 23 lines inside of wordpad

Comment: 1. You read the file until you locate the last line,  
2. remember its index/offset,  
3. read in your last line,  
4. modify in memory what you want,  
5. reset the file to the insert point you remember from step 2, and finally,   
6. write out your new set of values.

That's just basic file IO. If you are worried about simultaneous read/writes, you can protect it using various resource protectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read and save the file:

```
StringBuilder newTextFile = new StringBuilder();
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"1.txt");
foreach (string l in lines)
{
   // logic to replace last number, saved in string newLine
   // you can find the last        
   newTextFile.Append(newLine + "\r\n");
}
File.WriteAllText(@"1.txt", newTextFile.ToString());
```

To change the line (off the top of my head, test it!):

```
int locationAt = line.LastIndexOf(',');
string newLine = line.Substring(0, locationAt) + newValue + line.Substring(locationAt);
```

OR:

```
string[] values = line.Split(',');
values[values.Length - 1] = 'somethingelse';
string newLine = string.Join(",", values);
```

Comment: Note that the memory footprint of this program is more than twice the size of the entire file.

Comment: @Servy you are right. But the text file itself is a error. The data should be in a proper format.

Comment: the data is motion capture data taken from kinect, anyway, wouldn't the last string be the newline? is it part of the last string? or is it completely ignored?

Comment: The code change the last number of each line to a new one.

Comment: @JohnDemetriou Like Servy is pointing, the code performance is not good, consider it a temporary solution. The best way to go is to write a program to import the text file to a more reliable format and then change the data. This code, also, is not threat safe, meaning that you need to be sure that a instance of the program ended before calling a new one.

Comment: I do want it for a temporal solution since I want to edit a series of files and fix an error in the way they were saved and then start doing other stuff. This solution was simple for me to understand and fast to implement so I can move on with the actual data analysis

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do runs foul of a limitation in the low-level file I/O API in both Windows and POSIX; specifically, it is *impossible* to insert or delete bytes in the middle of a file, except by rewriting the entire file.  There are two usual ways to "rewrite the entire file":

- Read the entire file, and write it back out to a *new* file, with your desired changes. When you're done, close both files, delete the old file, and rename the new one to the old name.  (The "delete the old file" step is only necessary on Windows, and, unfortunately, introduces a a race window in which simultaneous readers may find that the file does not exist under the proper name.)  This is the preferred technique, because it's easier to code correctly, doesn't require you to hold the entire file in memory temporarily, doesn't corrupt the file if the computer crashes in the middle of the operation,<sup>1</sup> and guarantees that concurrent readers will see either the new file or the old one, not some combination of the two.  However, it requires scratch disk space equal to the larger of the old or new files.
- Read the entire file into memory. Make your changes to your in-memory representation of the file (which could be as simple as a big string or a list of strings). Rewind the file handle and write everything back out, starting from the beginning. (Technically you only have to write everything after the point of the first change, but that requires you to know the byte offset of the first change, which is usually more trouble than it's worth.)  If the result is shorter than the original, use `truncate` or equivalent to cut off the excess.  This requires no extra scratch disk space, but concurrent readers are likely to see a garbled combination of the two files, and the file is likely to be destroyed if the computer crashes in the middle of the operation.  You can mitigate the concurrent-readers problem with file locking, but be aware that some file locking mechanisms are *advisory*, i.e. only effective against readers that are aware that locking might be going on.

<sup>1</sup> Some OSes and/or filesystems require a call to `fsync` on the new file, *before* the rename, to ensure data integrity if the computer crashes in a tens-of-minutes-long window *after* the rename.  This is a bug in these systems.

Comment: It's not the *only* way.  Reading the whole file into memory and then overwriting the file's contents may be an option in this case as well.

Comment: But be aware Servy's solution trades one race for another where a reader may read a half written file.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain True.  Ideally you'd just synchronize all file access to one thread and just have multiple workers, if possible.

Comment: I am the only reader, I wish to edit motion capture files for later reasearch

Comment: @Servy That's what I'm talking about when I say "Technically one *can* overwrite ..."

Comment: @JohnDemetriou I understood "simultaneous reading and writing," in the title of your question, to imply that there were (potentially) multiple processes reading and writing the file at the same time.  See edits.

Comment: @Zack no, I guess it was not properly written. I meant simulltaenously read, edit, writeback

Answer (score 1):

You should consider either memory mapped files:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/salvapatuel/archive/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4.aspx

or perhaps a managed ESENT wrapper:

http://managedesent.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PersistentDictionaryDocumentation&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 1):

Why not read the file with `ReadAllLines()`, do the replacement with `Regex.Replace()`, and then `WriteAllLines()`?

**Edit:** 
In detail:

```
string[] lines = File.WreadAllLines("file.txt");
int lastnum;
for(int i=0;i<lines.Count;i++)
    lines[i]=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(lines[i], @",(\d+)$", m => 
    { 
        lastnum = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value);
        // Do any operations on lastnum
        return "," + lastnum.ToString(); 
    });

File.WriteAllLines("file.txt",lines);
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer with more info about Regex.Replace?

Answer (score 1):

Should be as simple as this:

```
List<string> myLines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").ToList();
foreach (string s in myLines)
{
    //whatever you're doing to each line
}

File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", myLines);
```

Comment: Will writeAllLines overwrite the old file?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou, Yes. If you want to keep the old file, you'll have to back it up, or save the new file with a different name.

Answer (score 0):

since you only change the last number after comma of each line, what you can do is read line by line and get the last index of comma and then get the sub string. you can add all these last numbers to a list. work on this list and finally write in to the file.

Comment: I want it to be added right in the spot of the number I edited though, that was my actual question